# Change navigation item back button title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

How to change `< Wish list` button on something different?
[image]

Comment: what do you want to change? You can set it on your storyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the title of the "back" button on a Navigation Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449339/how-do-i-change-the-title-of-the-back-button-on-a-navigation-bar)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471164/how-to-set-back-button-text-in-swift

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backItem];

Comment: i just want to change title

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code if any error then tell me

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Pending"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(flipView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButton;
```

}
-(void)flipView
{
}

Comment: this is impossible to do with story board ?

Comment: no it is work in storyboard i was try it early in my app

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "SomeOtherTitle", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "back:")
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.popViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```