# How do I get back button effect (<)

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am writing an app , where I want custom back effect of the default OS. Like the system which is giving with Settings ( `<`)
`< Icon`

Refer this image (I want the effect like Settings with the `<`)

[image]

**I already have the functionality, I just want the look and feel.**

Effect what I am getting.
I have tried the following
`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancel")`

Also, I have tried adding it via Storyboard. How do I get it ?

Comment: Are you only asking how to add the visual effect for the button, and not the functionality for it?

Comment: Is this view being pushed onto a UINavigationController? Or is it being presented modally?

Comment: Have you tried setting the backBarButtonItem instead of leftBarButtonItem? 

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471164/how-to-set-back-button-text-in-swift

Comment: In that case you really shouldn't be using a back button at all. Having a Done or Cancel button is what you should be doing. Back buttons with < are used specifically for when you are pushing hierarchical view controllers onto a navigation controller. When displaying things modally like this you should not use them. You shouldn't really be using the word "Back" at all here.

Comment: @Armin the back button is only used when the view controller is pushed onto a navigation controller. This is not happening in this case.

Comment: If it is being used in a "show" segue on a navigation controller then the back button will show the title of the previous screen alongside the <. So if you were to push a view on top of the login view controller here you would automatically get a "< Login" button. You can change the text by setting the `backBarButtonItem` on the Login screen to change what other screens show when you should go back to the Login screen.

Comment: @onkar use a "show" segue like I said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118415/discussion-between-onkar-and-fogmeister).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `backBarButtonItem` and you will get right effect.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancel")
```

Also, you make sure

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` will be shown only after your have pushed another one view to navigation stack, controlled by `self.navigationController`, if no left button on navigation bar is displayed.