# Use only custom image for navigationItem backBarButton Item

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to remove the title and use only custom image for back button in Navigation Controller.
I came across questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18870128/3207014) and I have tried this:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: Constants.Image.kClose), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

I am putting this in `viewDidLoad()` of the View Controller which is pushing a `UITabbarController`. ( I know its not a very good idea to push Tab Bar in a Navigation Controller, but I need to do this).

I am getting the following result:
[image: Navigation Bar]

But I don't want that default blue back button. I just want my custom close button to appear there. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why you not set image to the left  bar button item ? Is it not working? Instate blue back button image ... Or clear color blue back button.

Comment: Setting left button item isn't working. I don't understand `instate blue back button image`

Comment: Check this post may helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504860/how-to-change-back-button-title-on-navigation-controller-in-swift3/40505660#40505660

Answer (score 0):

Create a bar button

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)backButton {
    UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 4, 34, 34)];
    leftButton.layer.cornerRadius = leftButton.frame.size.width / 2;
    leftButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
    return leftBarButton;
}
```

and set like this

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self backButton];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
```

Comment: What is `setBackIndicatorImage `?

Comment: /*
 The back indicator image is shown beside the back button.
 The back indicator transition mask image is used as a mask for content during push and pop transitions
 Note: These properties must both be set if you want to customize the back indicator image.
 */

Comment: But what is the selector `setBackIndicatorImage ` ? Where is it defined? The compiler is throwing error if I use that.