# (Swift) fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexpath

I have three arrays. One displays headers for each section on the tableView, one displays titles, and one has the links for each cell. When I run this code, I get:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

[Here is what happens after it runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxLnZ.png)

my code is:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var headers = ["Bein Sports", "Sky Sports", "Alkass", "Other"]

    var channels = [["Bein Sports 1","Bein Sports 2","Bein Sports 3","Bein Sports 4","Bein Sports 5","Bein Sports 6","Bein Sports 7","Bein Sports 8","Bein Sports 9","Bein Sports 10","Bein Sports News"],
                              ["Sky Sports 1","Sky Sports 2","Sky Sports 3","Sky Sports 4","Sky Sports 5"],
                              ["Alkass One", "Alkass Two", "Alkass Three", "Alkass Four", "Alkass Five"],
                              ["BT Sports 1", "BT Sports 2", "Real Madrid TV", "Real Madrid TV 2"]]

    var links = [["https://www.google.ca","https://www.facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com"],
                 ["https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com"],
                 ["https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com","https://facebook.com"],
                 ["http://twitter.com","http://facebook.com","http://www.google.com","http://www.instagram.com"]]

    var myIndex = 0

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return channels[section].count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return channels.count //Rows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return headers[section] //Sections
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = channels[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] //TextLabel
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = [indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

in the debugger this is the highlighted line:

```
myIndex = [indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
```

Comment: What is the value of `IndexPath` (section, row)?

Comment: This is the same problem [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712469/swift-array-of-urls-not-working). Did you review the answers there and the changes you made?

Comment: @rmaddy this is the correct question.

Comment: But the line causing the issue is the same line you asked about [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712469/swift-array-of-urls-not-working). You were given answers about fixing that line of code. So why are you posting a new question with the same bad line of code?

Comment: @rmaddy I had errors in the code that were already corrected and answers were trying to solve both. I attempted to do what the answers said but it was all messed up on my end and I didn't know what is what.

Comment: The code `myIndex = [indexPath.section][indexPath.row]` shouldn't even compile, let alone run. Is that actually your "real" code?

Comment: Yes, I'm a brand new coder, learning off internet. The code used to be: 

    myIndex = indexPath.row

but it used to refer only to the first link in the "links" array and I wouldn't get an error. So I added the "indexPath.section" thinking it would solve it.

Comment: @rmaddy can you help me? It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you want help you need to post real code that is causing your issue. The code in your question won't even compile so it can't be causing the error you claim.

Comment: @rmaddy I've posted an image showing exactly what happens.

Comment: It's not valid code. I'm amazed it compiles. The real question is why is `myIndex` an `Int` when you need to store the whole `IndexPath`?

Comment: @rmaddy what should I change?

Comment: @rmaddy it compiles because it says make an array containing `indexPath.section` and then access the `indexPath.row`th element. Which if row is anything other than 0 is going to be a bound violation. It is valid but totally incorrect code.

Comment: @KarrarAl-Mimar what are you actually trying to achieve with that `myIndex...` line?

Comment: @Paulw11 I have a table and I want it so that when I click each cell it takes me to the same screen that has WKWebView which will be filled from the array "links". I learned online that I need to declare "myIndex = 0" so that the arrays are accessible by order, starting from 0.

Comment: In `prepareForSegue` you can use `tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow`.  The code you are then looking for to get the url is `links[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`

Comment: @Paulw11 Of course. That makes sense (about why the code compiles).

Comment: @Paulw11 Is that the exact code I add? Can you write it out exactly because I attempted to do as you said but I don't think I wrote it correctly. Thnx man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store  myIndex as IndexPath and using myIndex to get indexPath row and section just like this

```
     var myIndex : IndexPath = IndexPath()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      myIndex = NSIndexPath(row: indexPath.section, section: indexPath.row) as IndexPath
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
 }
```

Comment: Do not use `NSIndexPath` in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy Why is that?

Comment: @KarrarAl-Mimar Because you use `IndexPath`. Why create an `NSIndexPath` just to cast it to `IndexPath`? That's pointless. It's Swift. Use Swift APIs, not Objective-C APIs.