# How do I delete a UINavigationController's back button title?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I want to get rid of the title on a navigation bar's back button.  It keeps crowding the title of my view controller.

How do I hide it using Swift 3?

This doesn't work:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = nil
```

Comment: are you using storyboards ?

Comment: No, all programmatically. None of these answers work. I don't have a clue why.

Answer (score 1):

Add either

`self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)`

or

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = ""`

to your `prepare:forsegue:` if you use storyboard or before navigating.

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKS:

I had to put:

```
self.navigationItem.title = ""
```

That's it. If anybody can explain why this works, and the other posted answers don't, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me . . replace `nil` with `""` (**Swift 3**)

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "Back"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem // This will show in the next view controller being pushed
}
```

More detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32284525/4935811

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `A` ViewController pushes `B` ViewController. And you wan't to remove the back button title in ViewController `B`. Then You need to set the `backBarButtonItem` of the `A` ViewController. Something like this.

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
    }
}
```