# How to change the position of navigationItem titleView

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to create custom titleView and change the position to be next to the back button.

The titleView should be look like :

[image: screenshot]

So what i did was :

```
private func setupNavigationItems() {

    let label = UILabel()

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    label.text = "Info"
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.textAlignment = .left
    navigationItem.titleView = label

    if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    }

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
}


override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()
    setupNavigationItems()
}
```

It works, but in some situation i get crash :

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors
>    and
>    because they have no common
>   ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in
>   different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

How can i fix this crash?, there is a better way to change the position of the navigation title?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get that effect you want to use:

**navigationItem.backBarButtonItem**

and not:

**navigationItem.titleView**

the backBarButtonItem will automatically show the title of your previous viewcontroller but can be modified to anything you like as shown here:

[How to set back button text in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471164/how-to-set-back-button-text-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

replace this code :-

```
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.widthAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
```

with this code :-

```
label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8).isActive = true
```

Change multiplier according your need.

**OR**

set frame of UILabel without constraint.

```
let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width * 0.8, height: 44))
lbl.text = "Info"
lbl.textColor = .black
lbl.textAlignment = .left
navigationItem.titleView = lbl
```