# Master-Detail-Application change the "Back" Button iPad(Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

To show you my issue I created a new Master-Detail-Application in Xcode 10.1 and with the deployment target iOS 12.1 (I tried other iOS versions too)

I want to change the text of the "Back" Button in the top left corner at the Detail View, which is by default "Master".

I have come up with the following code, which I wrote in the `-(void)viewDidLoad` method in DetailViewController.m .

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Menu", @"Menu");
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.leftBarButton animated:YES];
```

When I know start the App, the Button is how it should be, but as soon as I press it, it changes back to "Master" and stays that way.

I have tried to put this code anywhere you can imagine, but nothing worked.
I tried several other methods I found online and nothing else worked for me.

EDIT:

I just found out, it only affects iPad, when I test it on iPhone, the button displays correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471164/how-to-set-back-button-text-in-swift

Comment: @Logic but I need to use Objective C, are there differences between the solution?

Comment: try second solution.it is using storyboard.

Comment: I dont know why, but it doesnt work for me.
It still displays "Master"