# UINavigation text

Tags: swift, uikit

How can I change the text on the navigation bar programmatically ? My implementation below doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    viewModel?.image = nil
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.view.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

[image]

Comment: What text are you referring to? Back button text? or the "Take Selfie' title? If it's the latter you can simply give a text to the `self.title` property inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471164/how-to-set-back-button-text-in-swift solve your problem?